# Verifying Kalman filter's answer

Tags: kalman-filter

So, I have applied kalman filter on this [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Dataset+for+ADL+Recognition+with+Wrist-worn+Accelerometer). Following is my code (please note I am adding entire code for one to reproduce results on his/her machine).

```
# Multi dimensional Kalman filter
import os
from math import *

class matrix:

    # implements basic operations of a matrix class

    def __init__(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            print "lol"
        self.value = value

        self.dimx = len(value)
        self.dimy = len(value[0])
        if value == [[]]:
            self.dimx = 0

    def zero(self, dimx, dimy):
        # check if valid dimensions
        if dimx < 1 or dimy < 1:
            raise ValueError, "Invalid size of matrix"
        else:
            self.dimx = dimx
            self.dimy = dimy
            self.value = [[0 for row in range(dimy)] for col in range(dimx)]

    def identity(self, dim):
        # check if valid dimension
        if dim < 1:
            raise ValueError, "Invalid size of matrix"
        else:
            self.dimx = dim
            self.dimy = dim
            self.value = [[0 for row in range(dim)] for col in range(dim)]
            for i in range(dim):
                self.value[i][i] = 1

    def show(self):
        for i in range(self.dimx):
            print self.value[i]
        print ' '

    def __add__(self, other):
        # check if correct dimensions
        if self.dimx != other.dimx or self.dimy != other.dimy:
            raise ValueError, "Matrices must be of equal dimensions to add"
        else:
            # add if correct dimensions
            res = matrix([[]])
            res.zero(self.dimx, self.dimy)
            for i in range(self.dimx):
                for j in range(self.dimy):
                    res.value[i][j] = self.value[i][j] + other.value[i][j]
            return res

    def __sub__(self, other):
        # check if correct dimensions
        if self.dimx != other.dimx or self.dimy != other.dimy:
            raise ValueError, "Matrices must be of equal dimensions to subtract"
        else:
            # subtract if correct dimensions
            res = matrix([[]])
            res.zero(self.dimx, self.dimy)
            for i in range(self.dimx):
                for j in range(self.dimy):
                    res.value[i][j] = self.value[i][j] - other.value[i][j]
            return res

    def __mul__(self, other):
        # check if correct dimensions

        if self.dimy != other.dimx:
            raise ValueError, "Matrices must be m*n and n*p to multiply"
        else:
            # subtract if correct dimensions
            res = matrix([[]])
            res.zero(self.dimx, other.dimy)
            for i in range(self.dimx):
                for j in range(other.dimy):
                    for k in range(self.dimy):
                        res.value[i][j] += self.value[i][k] * other.value[k][j]
            return res

    def transpose(self):
        # compute transpose
        res = matrix([[]])
        res.zero(self.dimy, self.dimx)
        for i in range(self.dimx):
            for j in range(self.dimy):
                res.value[j][i] = self.value[i][j]
        return res

    # Thanks to Ernesto P. Adorio for use of Cholesky and CholeskyInverse functions

    def Cholesky(self, ztol=1.0e-5):
        # Computes the upper triangular Cholesky factorization of
        # a positive definite matrix.
        res = matrix([[]])
        res.zero(self.dimx, self.dimx)

        for i in range(self.dimx):
            S = sum([(res.value[k][i])**2 for k in range(i)])
            d = self.value[i][i] - S
            if abs(d) < ztol:
                res.value[i][i] = 0.0
            else:
                if d < 0.0:
                    raise ValueError, "Matrix not positive-definite"
                res.value[i][i] = sqrt(d)
            for j in range(i+1, self.dimx):
                S = sum([res.value[k][i] * res.value[k][j] for k in range(self.dimx)])
                if abs(S) < ztol:
                    S = 0.0
                res.value[i][j] = (self.value[i][j] - S)/res.value[i][i]
        return res

    def CholeskyInverse(self):
        # Computes inverse of matrix given its Cholesky upper Triangular
        # decomposition of matrix.
        res = matrix([[]])
        res.zero(self.dimx, self.dimx)

        # Backward step for inverse.
        for j in reversed(range(self.dimx)):
            tjj = self.value[j][j]
            S = sum([self.value[j][k]*res.value[j][k] for k in range(j+1, self.dimx)])
            res.value[j][j] = 1.0/tjj**2 - S/tjj
            for i in reversed(range(j)):
                res.value[j][i] = res.value[i][j] = -sum([self.value[i][k]*res.value[k][j] for k in range(i+1, self.dimx)])/self.value[i][i]
        return res

    def inverse(self):
        aux = self.Cholesky()
        res = aux.CholeskyInverse()
        return res

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value)


########################################

# filter function

def kalman_filter(x, P):

        # measurement update

        y = measurements - H * x

        s = H * P * H.transpose() + R
        K = P * H.transpose() * s.inverse()
        x = x + K * y
        P = (I - K * H) * P

        # prediction
        x = F * x  
        P = F * P * F.transpose()
        return x,P

files = []
x = matrix([[0.], [0.], [0.]]) # initial state (location and velocity)

P = matrix([[1000., 0.,0.], [0., 1000.,0.] , [0.,0.,1000.]]) # initial uncertainty
u = matrix([[0.], [0.]]) # external motion
F = matrix([[1., 0., 0.], [0., 1.,0.], [0.,0.,1.] ]) # next state function
H = matrix([[1., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]]) # measurement function
R = matrix([[1., 0., 0.], [0.,1.,0.], [0., 0., 1.]]) # measurement uncertainty
I = matrix([[1., 0.,0.], [0., 1.,0.], [0.,0.,1.]]) # identity matrix
for i in os.listdir("/home/fatima/Downloads/thesis/HMP_Dataset/Climb_stairs"):
    if i.endswith('.txt'):
        files.append(i)






for j in range(len(files)-1):
    print "iterationh number"
    print j
    with open("/home/fatima/Downloads/thesis/HMP_Dataset/Climb_stairs/"+files[j]) as f:

        content = f.readlines()
        for e in range(len(content)-1):
            content1 = [z.strip() for z in content]
            content2 = content1[e].split(" ")
            content2[0] =-14.709 + (float(content2[0])/63)*(2*14.709);
            content2[2] =-14.709 + (float(content2[2])/63)*(2*14.709);
            content2[1] =-14.709 + (float(content2[1])/63)*(2*14.709);
            measurements =matrix([ [float(content2[0]) ], [float(content2[1])] , [float(content2[2])] ] )
            print measurements



            x,p=  kalman_filter(x, P)
            print x
```

Kalman filter is at the end of the code. I haven't added any noise in the prediction of state matrix as I am unsure of how to. 
**About Dataset:**
It is an ADL wrist-worn accelerometer dataset. There are a total of 14 activities and the acceleration is recorded in x,y and z-direction. Values of acceleration vary from 0 to 63. For the calculation, it is normalized to -14.7 to +14.7.
**Question:**
My question is whether I am headed in the right direction or not. Does the output seem to be correct? Any improvements?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good and you definitely heading in the right direction!

Here are some thinks you can do to check your implementation:

- consider simple cases for which you know the solution, for example H = I, P = sigma²*I and R = sigma'² * R. x should tend toward the x of the previous time step of sigma tends to zero and x should tend toward the measurements if sigma' tends to zero. Or if sigma = sigma', then the Kalman Filter analysis should be the average of the previous state and the measurements and P should be reduced by a half. You might want to write a unit test for these cases.
- check that the matrix P stays always symmetric and positive defined (all eigenvalues are positive)
- Implement an alternate Kalman Filter update step, see equation (28) on page 39 of the document http://modb.oce.ulg.ac.be/mediawiki/upload/Alex/AssimLecture/assim_lecture.pdf. Essentially you can compute the Kalman gain also as:

K = inv(inv(P) + H' * inv(R) H ) H' inv(R)

where inv(P) is the inverse of the matrix P. Both should be equal up to the numerical precision.

For the model noise, you can just add a small covariance matrix to the equation P = F * P * F' + Q.  It is often a matrix proportional to the identity matrix. If Q is to small, measurement will no longer affect the analysis after some iterations. If Q is too large, you model state x will be quite noisy.

Some coding remarks:

- If `measurements`, `H` and `R` are also parameters of the Kalman_filter function, then your function would be more easily portable to a different case.
- Are you aware of numpy for matrix operations? It has a extensive support for matrix and array operations and uses highly optimized libraries for the computation.

Let me know if this helps!